# Representing a bounded open set as the union of a sequence of non-overlapping intervals

Tags: general-topology

On page 12， Measure and Category, John Oxtoby, the first line of proof of Lemma 3.6

> $G$ (a bounded open set) can be represented as the union of a sequence of non-overlapping intervals $I_i$.

It seems to me, $G$ is a subset of an "Euclidean $r$-space($r =1,2 ...$)", "intervals" are "rectangular parallelepiped with edges paralled to the axes" as the setting lay down in the beginning of this chapter.

I know it's true for $r = 1$, but how to show it's true when $r > 1$?

Comment: Questions: (1) $G \subset \mathbb{R^n}$?, (2) Any kind of interval, or closed, open,... - any restrictions?

Comment: @gnometorule: Both yes from the first paragraph of chapter 3, and  lemma 3.6 doesn't mention these things, so I assume it should accord with the former.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider the countable set $S$ of intervals $[a_i,b_i[$ with $a_i\in\frac1 {2^k}\mathbb Z^n$ and $b_i=a_i+\frac1{2^k}(1,\ldots,1)^T$ for some $k\in\mathbb Z$.
Given $G$, let $A=\{I\in S\mid I\subseteq G, \forall J\in S\colon I\subseteq J\subseteq G\to J= I\}$.
Then $\bigcup A=G$ and if $I,J\in A$ with $I\ne J$ then $I\cap J=\emptyset$. And of course $A$ is countable.